# HP Pavilion i5 Gaming fan noise

Tags: laptop, fan, overheating

I have an HP Pavilion i5 Gaming laptop and I had experienced some fan problems before. It had been producing an unusual lousy noise when the laptop's temperature goes high. I'm no longer experiencing that problem since I'm not getting my laptop to overheat anymore.

However, I'm considering buying some compressed air to use it on my laptop without opening it, as it's still new. So can this be effective?

BTW, I have changed some performance settings regarding the CPU usage: I've set its maximum to about 70% as i don't run large games on it . Does this help avoiding that fan noise or should I set the setting to its default value?

Comment: Compressed air made a difference for me - temp drop of around 20C when I blew out the dust without opening the case.

Comment: wow! that's great. But how frequently should i use it ?

Comment: I've been doing it every few weeks - but I'm a smoker ...

Comment: note that the 20C Drop was from the first time I cleaned it in something like 5 years ...

Comment: For me , i will try my best to keep the laptop away from dust after the first cleanup